# Linear regression problem with multi-dimensional vectors instead of scalar values as predictions

Tags: regression, optimization, matrix, gradient-descent

### Goal

I have a training set $S$ that contains a number of $(x, y)$ pairs, where $x$ and $y$ are vectors of same dimension ($K$). My goal is to find a projection matrix so $\phi^*$ of dimension $K \times K$such that

$$\phi^* = \text{argmin}_{\phi}  \sum_{(x,y) \in S}{|| \phi x - y ||^2}$$

This is a typical linear regression problem. The only difference is that our predictions $y$ are multi-dimensional vectors instead of scalar values (i.e., it is a [multivariate linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33381686/395857)).

---

### Gradient

To find $\phi^*$, I use gradient descent. Assume $S$ only contains one pair $(x, y)$. Let $\{\phi_{i, j} |(i, j) \in K^2\}$ be the elements of $\phi$, and $L(\phi) =  ||\phi x - y ||^2$.

By definition of the Euclidean distance, $||\phi x - y ||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^K{(\sum_{j=1}^K}\phi_{i, j}x_j-y_i)^2$.

Plugging it into the gradient, $\forall (r, c) \in K^2$:

$$ \frac{L(\phi)}{\delta\phi_{r, c}} =  \frac{||\phi x - y ||^2}{\delta\phi_{r, c}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^K{(\sum_{j=1}^K}\phi_{i, j}x_j-y_i)^2}{\delta\phi_{r, c}} = \frac{{\sum_{j=1}^K}(\phi_{r, j}x_j-y_r)^2}{\delta\phi_{r, c}}$$

Hence by the chain rule:
$$ \frac{L(\phi)}{\delta\phi_{r, c}} = 2x_c \sum_{j=1}^K (\phi_{r, j}x_j  -y_r ) $$

which gives us the following gradient descent update:

$$\phi_{r, c} \leftarrow \phi_{r, c} - \alpha  \frac{L(\phi)}{\delta\phi_{r, c}} $$

i.e.

$$\phi_{r, c} \leftarrow \phi_{r, c} - \alpha (2x_c \sum_{j=1}^K (\phi_{r, j}x_j  -y_r ) ) $$

where $\alpha$ is the learning rate.

If $S$ contains more than one $(x, y)$ pair: $S = \{(x^{(s)}, y^{(s)})|s\in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq s \leq \text{training set size} \}$

we would have a similar gradient descent update, with simply an additional sum over the training samples:

$$\phi_{r, c} \leftarrow \phi_{r, c} - \alpha \sum_{s=1}^{|S|} (2x^{(s)}_c \sum_{j=1}^K (\phi_{r, j}x^{(s)}_j  -y^{(s)}_r ) ) $$

---

### Question

My matrix derivations skills are rusty: could I have computed the gradient descent update staying at the matrix and vector levels without going down to scalars?

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Comment: @O.rka Not really, though I thought somebody had written an answer.