# Machine learning | Classifier method that uses distributions instead of scalar point values?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, classification, prediction, algorithms

I usually use `Random Forest` or `Logistic Regression` classifiers.  My data looks something like this in the toy example below where each `i,j` value is an `int` or `float`:

## A

[image]
I have been experimenting with some feature reduction techniques and realized some of the `attributes` I can actually just group together.  After grouping them, I end up with a distribution.  In the toy example below, they are normally distributed but they can be anything.

In `Python 3` with `SciPy`, I could populate with `i_j = scipy.stats.norm(loc=0, scale=1)` for each of the cells .

## B

[image]

**My question is if there are any algorithms that can take in distributions as the training data?** For example, if I trained on something like **B** and predicted on something like **A**.  Sorry if this is a dumb question but I have been thinking about it and wanted to ask the community if it is something familiar to anyone.

I tried looking it up but I'm not entirely sure what to search.  I saw [Linear regression problem with multi-dimensional vectors instead of scalar values as predictions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178109/linear-regression-problem-with-multi-dimensional-vectors-instead-of-scalar-value) but it was a little different.

Comment: Have you tried using the parameters of the distributions as features?

Comment: Hmm... I haven't tried that.  Do you mean for each attribute in this case have 2 values for `mu` and `std` like `attribute_0_mu` and `attribute_0_std`?

Comment: Yes, sounds as informative as using the actual distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You can devise your own strategies. As I previously commented, you could use the parameter estimates from the distributions as features.

Another possibility I thought is to use quantiles as features. How many percentiles to use depends on how much you want to reduce the dimension of your task.

Basically, summary statistics as features sound as a good idea in this case.